# Why did programming languages originally use "&&" instead of "and"?

Tags: history, language-design

Why do we use "&&" instead of "and" in so many languages? I get that it has sort of become the standard for programmers, but how did that originally happen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the history of programming language design.

Comment: "Tradition"? "Language author preference"? Also, FWIW: LISP (~1958) is older than C (~1973), and does not traditionally use "&&".

Comment: Not entirely sure that this is off-topic for that reason, but I don't know if there's a "right" answer either.

Comment: Fortran actually used 'and'

Comment: I guess the question could kind of been answered in relation to the fact that there is a bitwise `&` while there is also logical `&&`. Why logical is a doubled bitwise? I mean, if it would be `both` instead of `and` it would be meaningless, apart from historical reasons, but here it is a bit more subtle and has some relation to programming (language design).

Comment: All other operators (+, -, *, !, ...) are symbollic instead of words like 'plus', 'minus', etc. So I'm guessing the use of '&' and '|' just follows the convention of using terse symbols...

Comment: Simply, We  are programmer, we are lazy and use '&&' look more pro.
...
and can be & and &&, so ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to the language designer to make these decisions, but one reason is that there is two types of `and` - regular and bitwise (`&& vs &`)

It's harder to succinctly express the bitwise version using English words

Answer (score 1):

> Why did programming languages originally use “&&” instead of “and”?

You have it back to front. Originally they used `and`: Fortran, Cobol, Algol, Pascal, PL/1, all the varieties of Basic, ...

It was the BCPL series of languages (B, C, C++) that introduced `&` and `&&` as far as I know, and Java and C# followed suit. You would have to ask the BCPL designers why, if they are still around.

APL used the set-theoretic symbols ^ and its inversion.

Comment: No, it really was C. BCPL had various conventions because of various character sets and B had just '&'. C added the '&&' mainly for short-circuit evaluation. We really can blame it all on C (as so many other things).